# Unable to add webpart

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to add a webpart, but when clicking on 'Add a Web Part' link the javascript debugger window shows an error :

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable  to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference 
wpadder.js, line 1 character 6109
```

The property is :

```
var k=this._getHiddenField("selZone").value
```

I'm using jquery-1.10.2 and bootstrap in my master page.

Comment: Sounds like this blog might help you: http://labs.steveottenad.com/type-mismatch-on-wpadder-js/

Comment: After spending 1 day debugging the issue I have noticed that the added HTML tags before the Sharepoint  tag mainly the Web Part Manager Tag  was the root cause of the issue 
Finally the reported error was not clear enough to simply catch the issue  but finally it worked out that way .